# send POST request html

Tags: html, post

I'm trying to create a post request from the following header.

```
POST /Create_New_Account.php HTTP/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------092818025341241
Content-Length: 198
Host: test.com
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

----------092818025341241
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

test@yahoo.com
----------092818025341241--
```

I tried using `http://test.com/Create_New_Account.php?email=test@yahoo.com`
but it didn't work i.e. no account was created. should i be adding anything else to my request?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using http://test.com/Create_New_Account.php?email=test@yahoo.com but it didn't work

Possibly, Create_New_Account.php uses `$_POST` in order to get parameter `email`, with given link `email` is accesible through `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` and not `$_POST`, which is why the overall create account operation fails.